# Table cells are empty in a uitableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a table with 1 section and many rows. Every cell contains some labels so I want to get their texts. My problem is, with the code below, I cant get the cells after I get first 5 cells. It is strange I know. To be clear, If I have 20 rows I can only get 5 cells with the code below, the rest 15 is null. However the for loop goes 20, First 5 cells are ok but the rest is empty..

All of the rows are same so there is no empty cell. What is my mistake?

```
        NSIndexPath  *indexPath;
        ReportTableCell *cell;

        for (int i = 0; i < [_tableReport numberOfRowsInSection:0] ; i++)
        {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];

            cell = (ReportTableCell *)[_tableReport cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the table view doesn't keep cells in the memory that are off the screen. This is an optimisation to reduce memory usage and speed up scrolling.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a):

> ```
> cellForRowAtIndexPath:
> ```
>
> **Return Value**
>  An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

You can only access the cells that are actually visible at the moment.

Comment: yes thats right. I can only see 5 rows.so how can I access all of the cells?

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to do that? You have to create your cells on the fly, when they become visible.

Comment: I need to combine all of the cell label texts and create a report. whats ur suggestion to do that?

Comment: Use your model. Never collect data from your GUI like that. Typically you would have an array of data objects (maybe just strings) in your view controller. When the table view asks your data source (the view controller) to create a cell for a given index, you setup the cell with the correct data from your array. And if you want a report with all the data, you already have them in your array.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView queues the cells for re-use purpose. It means if you have 100 rows, it is not guaranteed that it'll create 100 cells. Typically it'll create only visible cells and later re-use them for rest of the items to show. This is implemented somehow as below:

```
static NSString *MyCellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier"; 
UITableViewCell* cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];
//dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will give you the cells that has been added to queue after scroll and are ready for re-use.
if(cell == nil){
   // create new.
}
```

So technically you can't get all the cells. Alternative may be applied until you tell the exact purpose you trying to accomplish.